# How Can I Hover Image On Top Of Another?

Tags: css, image, hover

This might be really easy for many people but I just can't do it as I am not a developer. I am trying to hover image on top of another. It works but when I hover I can still see the another image at the background. When I hover the two images (same size) overlay each other and give different color.

Here is the CSS code:

```
.votebutton {
    text-align:center;
    background: transparent;
    width: 24px;
    height: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
    margin: -21px -28px 0px 0px;
}
.votebutton a: {
}
.votebutton a:hover {
    background-image: url(../img/thumbs.png);
    position:relative;
    display: inline;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 2;
    height: 5px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="vote" class="votebutton">{if $anonymous_vote eq "false" and $user_logged_in eq ""} 

   <a data-toggle="modal" href="#LoginModal" class="btn btn-mini {if $link_shakebox_currentuser_votes eq 1}btn-success{/if}">
```

{else} {if $link_shakebox_currentuser_votes eq 0}

here -- @Pinocchio -->
I would really appreciate if someone from 'stackoverflow community' can help me out. Thanks.

Edit: Have updated the full code. Thanks.

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: is your image transparent?

Comment: No, it isn't transparent. When I hover I want the 'hover image' to sit on top of another image. Right now both the images are showing when hover. The another background image should become invisible I guess. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't make sense how you can see both images. You'll need to set up a working code example so we can see what's going on. Check out jsFiddle or CodePen, or make up an HTML template and post it here. You can link to images at placehold.it

Comment: Easiest way I know is to get the offset and size of the original image within the page. I then create and append a new image to the page with a higher z-index and absolute positioning, setting the offset and size such that they match the original image.

Answer (score 0):

Im not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve. If it is simply a hover affect for you link then using :hover should work as you are attempting.

Here is a fiddle that does a basic background hover change - http://jsfiddle.net/f6Frt/1

You simply set a background image for you link, then change that on hover.

```
.votebutton a {
    padding: 20px;
    background-image: url('http://twimgs.com/informationweek/galleries/automated/818/Slide-1-opening-image-38launch_full.jpg');
    background-size: 100%;
}

.votebutton a:hover {
    color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    background-image: url('http://spaceinimages.esa.int/var/esa/storage/images/esa_multimedia/images/2004/01/reull_vallis_-_hrsc_image_15_january_20042/9758050-3-eng-GB/Reull_Vallis_-_HRSC_image_15_January_2004_node_full_image.jpg');
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

If you only want to show a background image on hover then omit the background from the css, as shown here http://jsfiddle.net/f6Frt/2

If you want to make the link text invisible then you can set its color to transparent:

```
.votebutton a:hover{color:rgba(0,0,0,0);}
```

shown here - http://jsfiddle.net/f6Frt/3/

If you want to take it a step further, you could use jQuery to clear the html content on hover, shown here - http://jsfiddle.net/f6Frt/4/ - this will require some extra tweaking, but is a good start if you're new to jQuery.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did exactly what you said. It works, but how do I make that 'LINK' invisible when hover? This is what I am talking about. When hover I want that blue color 'LINK' to be invisible and show only 'hover image'. Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: updated my answer for you. you can clear the text by making it transparent. Just update your link hover css with - color:rgba(0,0,0,0);

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your code works but unfortunately I just can't get what I want. Another link (image) is just floating on top. I like to try here again in this below HTML code. Is it possible to give hover here: <i class="icon-thumbs-up"> (this is an image)              
        <a class="vote linkVote_{$link_id}" {if $vote_from_this_ip neq 0 and $user_logged_in eq ""} data-toggle="modal" href="#LoginModal" {else} href="javascript:{$link_shakebox_javascript_vote}" {/if} title="{$title_short}" ><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i></a>

Comment: I have updated the entire code above. Thanks in advance. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: any chance you can recreate the problem in code pen? http://codepen.io/pen/ or the jsFiddle from above?